# Starting a job remotely

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I have a job which is scheduled to take around 1-2 days .Only option I have is to ssh into the machine (where it is going to run) using my home computer and start the job .Now my problem is that I want to use my home computer for other tasks during the interval and may be even shut it down /restart.So is there a way where I can start the job and ensure that it keeps on running even if I shut down the putty terminal on my home  machine?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) if you want to get back to it, or detach and background it otherwise.

Comment: ... or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)!

Comment: @salva, yes, or tmux.

Answer (score 2):

['nohup'](http://www.livefirelabs.com/unix_tip_trick_shell_script/june_2003/06022003.htm) is your friend